# In Excel, how do I have a line of code check what the value of a dropdown selection is. Then, how do I check that value vs another value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will first allow the user to easily transfer data to another sheet based on a dropdown list to select the month. I want the user to able to enter the date in the field I have created, then use buttons on the sheet to first select which month to paste though, then confirm the paste. I have twelve named ranges from Ref_Jan to Ref_Dec on a sheet named "DB - Ref Monthly" I am working on putting together the pieces but I'm stuck here with my test program:

```
   Sub Button8_Click()


Dim MonthSelector As Range
Dim Ref_May As Range

    If Range("MonthSelector") = Range("Ref_May") Then
            Sheets("DB - Ref Current").Range("Ref_Current").Copy
            Sheets("DB - Ref Monthly").Range("Ref_May").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
    End If




End Sub
```

My current plan is to use 12 if statements to refer to each month, as I already have the copy/paste portion of the code working in another sheet. If I am going about this all wrong I would not mind some guidance. Please let me know if I have been unclear and can provide additional information.

Comment: Firstly, I think you're fine hard-coding the months, instead of adding a reference sheet. This is an Excel app, not banking software, and the months are unlikely to change anytime soon. Secondly, what are you trying to do with the month value? If you're doing totally different things for each month, having 12 `if` statements makes sense. If you're doing almost the same thing for each month, it'd probably just be redundant. I'd suggest replacing `Application.Cells("L6") = "HEllo world"` with something representative of what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by hard coding the months. I've just named them Ref_<Month> as my variable. As for what I'm trying to do, I have a data set that I want to copy and paste to a location on another sheet, but I want that destination to change based on which month was selected in the dropdown list. I'll update my original code with what I have working so far to indicate it.

Comment: So, what exactly do `Range("MonthSelector")` and `Range("Ref_May")` refer to? Is `Range("MonthSelector")` a cell linked to the output of your dropdown? Is `Range("Ref_May")` the location you'd like to paste the data? Why would those two be equal? Also, what are the two `Dim` statements at the top for? Those values aren't used anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your help Josh, the range month selector is indeed a cell linked to the output of the dropdown. And the range ref_may is where I want to paste the date. I'm not quite sure if I'm getting the language wrong, but the reason they would be equal in my head is if I select a month in the dropdown, the value of that cell would be equal to the name of the range I am referring. Is this where i'm going wrong?

Comment: As for the dim statements, maybe I don't need them? I'm still very new to VBA and I'm still unsure as what I need to declare and what I don't

Answer (score 0):

Use looping to iterate months then no need to duplicate a code logic.

```
Dim arrMonth As New Collection
Dim idx As Integer
Dim val As String

Call arrMonth.Add("Jan")
Call arrMonth.Add("Feb")
Call arrMonth.Add("Mar")
'..etc..
Call arrMonth.Add("Dec")

For idx = 1 To arrMonth.Count
    val = arrMonth.Item(idx)
    Call MsgBox(idx & "=" & val)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Range("MonthSelector")` is a cell that has a value from a list of months (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.), and you've got corresponding named ranges `Ref_Jan`, `Ref_Feb`, `Ref_Mar`, etc., you could just do this:

```
Sub Button8_Click()
    Sheets("DB - Ref Current").Range("Ref_Current").Copy
    Sheets("DB - Ref Monthly").Range("Ref_" & Range("MonthSelector").Value).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```